# Connecting USB Internet to Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox, internet, usb-modem, .desktop

I have installed `Ubuntu Desktop 13.10` through `VirtualBox` which is running on `Windows 8`

I'm using `Reliance NetConnect+ ZTE` USB internet connection

I'm not able to connect Ubuntu to this internet.

I searched so many forums, i tried all the suggested steps but nothing is working. Please help me to connect the internet to Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you configured Windows 7 to use that adapter to connect Internet.

   Confirm that the USB adapter is not mounted to virtual box (Uncheck it if it was checked)

   [image]
2. Then just just setup a NAT adapter for Ubuntu VBox (to share Internet from Host OS with Guest OS):

   - Select Ubuntu virtual machine → Settings → Network
   - Check `Enable Network Adapter` & Select `Attached to` as `NAT`.

[image: Share Internet from Host OS]

Comment: I changed network to NAT in vbox, still its not working. Im on Windows 8

Comment: @sravis, Could I ask how did you connect the `NetConnect+ ZTE`, through VirtualBox USB? Do you have Internet on Windows8?

Comment: i have laptop which is running windows 8 as main os. In it i have installed vbox and ubuntu. i have reliance zte connected to my laptop usb. i dont have other internet connection

Comment: @sravis, updated answer, Do you have Internet on Windows8 while you are running VBox? because Ubuntu should connect through Windows8

Comment: Please check my laptop screen shots: Windows Internet Connection
http://s30.postimg.org/46ivhjhc1/windows_broadband.jpg

    VBOX Network Settings

http://s9.postimg.org/i5cdegcbj/virtual_box_network.jpg

    Ubuntu Desktop Through VBOX

http://s4.postimg.org/oxa53bukt/vbox_ubuntu.jpg

Comment: @Dhaksh, weird, your setup is correct. I'm sure what check next.